# How to test picture upload when multiple pictures (has_many) are allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Guide, which has_many Guide_pics.

guide.rb:

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :guide_pics, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guide_pics
end
```

guide_pic.rb:

```
class GuidePic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guide
  validates :guide_id, presence: true
  validate  :picture_size

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

The uploader is in the edit guide view.

Uploading a picture goes into my guides controller update function. There is nothing in my guide_pics controller.

It add pics correctly, but I'm confused on how to write a test to verify a picture is uploaded. I think I have to patch to the guide_path, so I tried this:

```
test "add guide pic" do
  log_in_as(@user)
  guide = @user.guide
  get edit_guide_path(guide)

  pic = fixture_file_upload('Can Tho-0676.jpg', 'image/jpg')
  assert_difference 'GuidePic.count', 1 do
    patch guide_path(guide), guide: { picture: pic }
  end
end
```

The patch does not throw an error. But it does not add a picture to guide.guide_pics.